# how to invoke an event that just got binded

Tags: jquery, events, initialization

Probably very stupid question but I can't find a satisfying solution.

I do have a list of anchors each displaying a different rss feed in a designated area on the page (div).

```
$(".rssfeed").bind('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.focus').removeClass('focus');
     $(this).addClass('focus');
     $('#rssarea').rssfeed($(this).attr('href'), {limit:10});
});
```

Now with jquery how do i invoke the click event on the first link, so that the rssarea gets populated with feeds and the link itself gets it's focus class? I was hoping for something like:

```
$('#rss1').sendEvent('click');
```

but sendEvent does not exist, any other solutions?

regards,
Jeroen.

Comment: Where did you got `sendEvent()` from? You made that up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger it:

```
$('#rss1').trigger('click');
```

Comment: You don't even have to retrieve it again.  `$('#rss1').click(function () { ... }).click();`

Comment: that was soo fast I can't even mark it as THE answer, probably tomorrow but it works!!

Comment: @dr jerry: You'll probably be able to within minutes.  Glad I could help.

Comment: @g.d.d.c but now the other rss's don't get the function attached to the click event?

Comment: @dr jerry: I don't think he realized you were assigning the click handler to the entire class, and only wanted to click one of them.

Comment: @Fosco - Good catch - I only kind of half-read the question.  :)  IF it were a single element being bound the short hand would save a bit of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
  $('#target').click();
```